# Sum up arrays of an array of object

Tags: javascript

I have the following array with objects, and the object consists of an array. I would like to return the total length of the array "species".

```
let fish = [
    {
        "name": "salmon", 
        "species": [
            {
                "name": "atlantic salmon",
                "gender": "male"
            },
            {
                "name": "sockeye salmon",
                "gender": "female"
            },
        ],
    },  
    {
        "name": "carp", 
        "species": [
            {
                "name": "grass carp",
                "gender": "male"
            },
            {
                "name": "common carp",
                "gender": "female"
            },
        ],
    },  
]
```

I would like to get back a result of 4 from this but I'm not too sure how. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Can you please add your attempt to the question?

Comment: *common salmon* is not a carp. Did you mean *common carp* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this line. It works fine.

```
let fish = [
    {
        "name": "salmon", 
        "species": [
            {
                "name": "atlantic salmon",
                "gender": "male"
            },
            {
                "name": "sockeye salmon",
                "gender": "female"
            },
        ],
    },  
    {
        "name": "carp", 
        "species": [
            {
                "name": "grass carp",
                "gender": "male"
            },
            {
                "name": "common salmon",
                "gender": "female"
            },
        ],
    },  
];
const speciesCount = fish.flatMap(f => f.species).length;
console.log(speciesCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.reduce` to accumulate the length of `species`

```
const res = fish.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el.species.length, 0)
```

```js
let fish = [
  {
    name: "salmon",
    species: [
      {
        name: "atlantic salmon",
        gender: "male",
      },
      {
        name: "sockeye salmon",
        gender: "female",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "carp",
    species: [
      {
        name: "grass carp",
        gender: "male",
      },
      {
        name: "common salmon",
        gender: "female",
      },
    ],
  },
]

const res = fish.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el.species.length, 0)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
let count = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < fish.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < fish[i][species].length; i++) {
    count++;
  }
}
```